# $K\subseteq L\subseteq M$ be fields. If $L/K$ and $M/L$ are both separable then $M/K$ is separable

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

So this is really an iff I'm trying to prove but the other direction was very straightforward. This is essentially what I'm trying.

Let $\alpha\in M$. Then we want to show that the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ is separable. Let $p(x)$ be this minimum polynomial. Then we can write

$$p(x)=q_1(x)q_2(x)\cdots q_m(x)$$

for some irreducible $q_i\in L[x]$. Then each $q_i$ is separable over $M$, so they all have distinct roots. What I am having trouble showing that this implies the roots of $p(x)$ are all distinct. How can I be sure $q_1$ doesn't have a root in common with $q_3$, for instance?

Comment: I have a proof, but it depends on the idea of going back and forth between separabiiity of an element over $K$, and separability of an extension $L\supset K$, as equality between the degree and the number of $K$-morphisms into an algebraically closed field. It also depends on the multiplicativity of separable degree. If you haven’t seen these concepts, I suppose my method of attack will not help you. But if you want to see my proof, say so here, and I’ll sketch out an answer.